# Config webform for read

Tags: 8, webforms

It is posible config webform for read but not submmit?
I need that anonymous user see webform but only authenticated user can send.

Answer (score 0):

If you customize your submit buttons, you can set up access controls that only allow authenticated users to see the submit buttons.

@see https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2983024